# Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder" Grails 5.3.2

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, grails, logback, slf4j

My company wants to upgrade to Grails 5 from 2.4.4, so I created a new project to play a bit with Grails 5 and get used to the new changes, I used Grails 5.3.2, JDK 1.8.0_201 and the latest Intellij IDEA Ultimate. By default Grails adds dependencies for slf4j:

1. org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.36
2. org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:1.7.36
3. org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.36

logback:

1. ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.11
2. ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.2.11

log4j:

1. org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.17.2
2. org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:2.17.2

These dependencies are added because they are needed by other dependencies (e.g. spring boot), so according to SLF4J documentation I at least have logback, so why am I getting this error? Especially when this is a new project that I haven't done anything else? I'm using Gradle 7.2 and if you want to reproduce this issue then: Open Intellij Idea -> Start new Grails Project with create-app, JDK 1.8.0_201 and Grails 5.3.2 -> Build Project and Run it with grails run-app

I tried adding other dependencies like slf4j-nop, same issue. I tried using latest versions but then other dependencies require slf4j 1.7.36. I also tried other jdks like 11.0.19 and 17.0.7 Lastly I checked grails dependency-report but even with the create-app default dependencies it's utter chaos and I can't make heads or tails.